# Unable to see Document IDs in a SharePoint 2010 site collection

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to configure the Document ID feature in my site collection, but I can't get the Document IDs to appear.   I have done the following:

1. Turned the Document ID feature on in Site Collection Features
2. Tried to install the feature via PowerShell (It says it's already installed)
3. Set "Document ID Settings" to assign IDs, to have the prefix "TEST", and to reset all Doc IDs in the site collection to begin with the prefix
4. Ran the "Document ID Enable/Disable Job" and "Document ID Assignment Job" from Central Admin (for the Web app which houses the site collection"
5. waited, reran jobs, tried IISRESET, etc

No matter what, I can't get the Document ID column to appear in any document library within the site collection.  I have this working on another server, so I'm not sure why it's not working this time. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We opened a case with Microsoft and finally fixed this same issue using this:

**Verify if web application / site has document ID enabled**

$web=get-spweb URL

$web.properties

**How to fix if documentID_enabled is set to 0:**

$web=get-spweb URL

$web.properties[“docid_enabled”]=”1”

$web.properties.update()

Answer (score 0):

Having done some more testing, I notice that for some reason this feature does not always work if the site collection is created with a Publishing Portal as the root site template. The feature seems to work fine if other templates are used when creating the site collection, including Enterprise Wiki. It does not seem to matter what template is used for sub-sites.

A good clue that the feature has not activated properly is that when you configure the Document ID in Site Collection Administration the prefix is initially blank.